# how to implement find or count on map  while mapping multidimensional int array to string in C++?

Tags: c++, dictionary

My original problem was how to map multidimensional int array to string.Following was the solution:thanks to Ikspeto

```
    map<int , map<int,string>> _myvar;
    _myvar[0][0] = "Some String00";
    _myvar[0][1] = "Some String01";
    _myvar[0][2] = "Some String02";
    _myvar[1][0] = "Some String10";
```

Now my problem is how to implement find or count method of map on this?

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `_myvar`?

Comment: this is where i need help sir

Comment: So you want something like `char *_myvar[2][3];`?

Comment: You want to convert strings to ints or ints to strings? The example appears to be the former but the question title specifies the latter. Also, "mapping to a string" is usually called "serialization", for example to save to a file. Is that what you want?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: he is assigning string literals to it, so at least a const char*, but snice he is asking about c++, he maybe means std::map and std::string, but then again he is talking about "int array" so maybe he has a int _myvar[x][y] ...

Comment: @Potatoswatter i want to map multidimensional int array to string. That is the title of my question

Comment: @PlasmaHH,Potatoswatter,Joachim Pileborg I got many downvotes. Is it because this is a bad approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not understand your question very well, but I think this is what you are looking for :

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
   map<int, map<int, string> > m; 

   m[0][0] = "one";
   m[1][3] = "two";
   cout<<m[0][0]<<endl;
   cout<<m[1][3]<<endl;
}
```

Note that you must leave a blank space after string> .

or

If you want to convert every character to int :

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string s;
   s = "one";

   int arr[2][10];

   int a = s.size();
   for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
   {
       arr[0][i] = s[i];
   }

   cout<<arr[0][0]<<" "<<(char)arr[0][1]<<endl;
}
```

EDIT

Post your full source code. My example is working at my local compiler. In the code sample you gave you are declaring a variable called _menu_item, but you are using _myvar. You may have declared _myvar differently somewhere in you full code.

For finding a map entry by the first value you can use find(). Find returns an iterator.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map<int , map<int,string> > _myvar, my;
    _myvar[0][0] = "Some String00";
    _myvar[0][1] = "Some String01";
    _myvar[0][2] = "Some String02";
    _myvar[1][0] = "Some String10";

    map<int , map<int,string> >::iterator it; /* This is an iterator for this kind of map.
    You can use it to assign a position to it from the map. */



    it = _myvar.find(0); //Like this
    _myvar.erase (it); // And use it for example like this


    _myvar[3] = _myvar.find(0)->second ; // The pointer ->second gives the second value of the map. In this case an another map.

}
```

For searching by value you can use this :

```
for (it = _myvar.begin(); it != _myvar.end(); ++it)
{
    if (it->second == value)
    {
        key = it->first;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that your comment is only valid in pre-11 versions of C++ standard.

Comment: Thanks your first one worked for me. But I have another problem how to implement map.find() for this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store strings in a 2D array directly, you can use:

```
std::string _myvar[10][20]
```

If you want an array of (const) pointers to C strings, then:

```
char* _myvar[10][20];
// or
const char* _myvar[10][20];
```

If you want a dynamically-sized array, use a `vector<vector<string>>` (or `boost::multi_array`  perhaps)